# How to execute plain Redis queries in PHP using predis

Tags: php, redis, predis, tile38

How can I send a raw command to `Redis` using the `PHP predis` package

```
$client->executeRaw('INTERSECTS vehicle LIMIT 1000 GET geofence geofence_id');
```

is it something applicable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to make your command an array.

```
$client->executeRaw(['INTERSECTS', 'vehicle', 'LIMIT', '1000', 'GET', 'geofence', 'geofence_id']);
```

See https://github.com/predis/predis#adding-new-commands for more information.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Josh, is there a way or workaround to execute the query above for 1000 geofences at one request?

Comment: Not that I can think of.